# how to list the size of static declarations in object file?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

I'm trying to reduce the size of an executable (using MINGW/GCC) by finding all large statically declared arrays. Is there a way to dump the list of data symbols along with their aggregate sizes?? I've looked at man pages for nm and objdump but dont see anything useful so far.

Thx.

Comment: Note that reducing the size of large static arrays will reduce the program's runtime memory footprint, which is probably what you intend in any case, but it will have no effect of the size of the .exe file unless those large arrays also happen to be fully initialised - if that were the case you would probably not need the toolchain to find them for you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`nm`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/binutils/nm.html#nm) utility from [GNU binutils](http://www.gnu.org/s/binutils/) with the `--print-size` option (abbreviated `-S`).  For example, to find the 20 largest symbols in an object file, do this:

```
nm --print-size --size-sort objfile.o | tail -20
```

Comment: i think nm has a bug. -S supposed to print size but it doesnt. It does so only with --size-sort flag.

Answer (score 3):

The linker can generate a MAP file which will provide that information.

If you are using gcc to compile and link, you pass linker options to the linker with:

```
-Wl,<comma-separate-options-list>
```

If calling ld directly, you obviously just pass the linker options.

The linker option you need is:

```
-Map=<mapfilename>
```

You may also use `--cref` to include a cross-reference table in the map file.

Comment: i see sizes reported only per object module with -M flag. Perhaps other flags are necessary for a breakdown?

Comment: @Saideira: Ah, haven't used GNU in a long time, my current compiler map file reports object sizes, worst-case stack usage, and all sorts of other useful information.  @Adam provided a good answer; go with that.

Comment: @Clifford out of curiosity, what compiler suite do you use?

Comment: @Saideira: Primarily (and the one to which I was referring) ARM RealView (part of Keil MDK-ARM).  I develop embedded systems, so that information it is probably entirely useless to you!